# Any way to know what user is logged in in renderEditor.template

Tags: templates, grails, groovy, spring-security

my question is: It there any way that in renderEditor.template know what user is logged in and what roles does he have? 
What I want to do: In my app i want some field change when logged user is admin ("ROLE_ADMIN") - normal user will have is html select tag only 1 option, by default selected, and when admin user will be logged in, list of all users appear.

I'm using Spring Security Plugin + Grails 2.1.1.

What I have already tried:

1. Add Spring Security Service (`def springSecurityService`) but it was always null
2. Try to pass boolean argument - no effect

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT** Many thanks for your answers. However, my question wasn't precised enough, so I include some pseudocode that maybe explain better what I want achieve (method from renderTemplate.template)

```
private renderManyToOne(domainClass,property) {
        if (property.association) {
            def sb = new StringBuilder()
            sb << '<g:select'
            ...
            if (/*loged user is admin*/) {
                sb << ' from="${' << property.type.name << '.list()}"'
            }else{
                sb << ' from="${user}"'/*only loged user can be selected*/
            }
            ...
            sb << '/>'
            sb as String
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a taglib with spring security
http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.1%20SecurityTagLib

In my app I use it like this:

```
<ul>
<sec:access expression="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <li><a href="#newFeedModal" role="button">Add New Feed</a></li>
</sec:access>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `renderEditor.template` is not rendered with the usual GSP template engine.  It's rendered with a standard `SimpleTemplateEngine` with just few simple bindings.  However, the *output* of this template then gets rendered with the GSP template engine.  It's fairly confusing, but you can have `renderEditor.template` output GSP code.  For example:

```
<%  if (property.type == Boolean || property.type == boolean)
        out << renderBooleanEditor(domainClass, property)
    else ...
    else if (property.type == String && domainInstance == 'specialField') {
        out << '''<g:if test="${org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')}">'''
        out << renderStringEditor(domainClass, property)
        out << '''</g:if>'''
        out << '''<g:else>'''
        out << renderStringSelectEditor(domainClass, property)
        out << '''</g:else>'''
    }
    ...
```